# poisson distribution over a histogram

Tags: python, graph, plot, matplotlib, distribution

this program is supposed to put a poisson distribution on a plotting graph. but when i run it nothing appears. i've tried to rearrange the code, but it tells me that x and y are not in the same dimension...

can someone figure it out?

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.special import gamma
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot
mu = 70
counts = range(45,101,1)
for counts in range(46,96,1):

p = exp(-mu) * mu**counts / gamma(counts +1)
pylab.plot(counts,p)


pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the gamma function... I believe you should use factorial instead, since the Poisson distribution is `P = e^(-L) * L^k / k!`

You may have grabbed the gamma function from the expression for a Gamma distribution, which is related to a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I'm not familiar with SciPy... I see that gamma(k + 1) is the same as factorial(k).

Answer (score 0):

You're using your 'x' variable as the iterated variable:

```
counts = range(45,101,1)
print "'counts' before for loop:",counts
for counts in range(46,96,1):
    pass
print "'counts' after for loop:",counts
```

counts has been reassigned to 95